# Sampling from transition model in particle filter

Tags: bayesian, bootstrap, particle-filter

I am reading the foundational paper about Bayesian bootstrap particle filter [(Gordon, Salmond, Smith, 1993)](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elemmon/courses/ee67033/pubs/GordonSalmondSmith93.pdf) and they are solving the following discrete time estimation problem: $x_k\in R^n$ , $$f_k:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$$ is the transition function $$x_{k+1}=f_k(x_k,w_k)\,, \quad\text{where }\ w_k \in \mathbb{R}^m$$ is a zero mean white noise,$$y_k:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^r \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^p$$ is the observation function$$y_k=h_k(x_k,v_k)\,, \quad y_k\in \mathbb{R}^p\,,\quad\text{where }\  v_k \in \mathbb{R}^p$$ is also a zero mean white noise and $D_k = \{y_i\}^{k}_{i=1}$.

The prediction step can be formulated recursively: $$p(x_k|D_{k-1})=\int p(x_k|x_{k-1})p(x_{k-1}|D_{k-1})$$ and if we assume that $$\hat{p}(x_{k-1}|D_{k-1}) = \sum^n_{i=1}{w_i\cdot \delta(x_{k-1}-x^i_{k-1})}$$ is represented by samples we can plugin into the equation above and get:
$$\hat{p}(x_{k}|D_{k-1})=\int p(x_k|x_{k-1})\hat{p}(x_{k-1}|D_{k-1})=\sum^{n}_{i=1}{w_i}p(x_k|x^{i}_{k-1})$$

In order to sample from $\hat{p}(x_{k}|D_{k-1})$ we need to sample from a mixture and one way of doing it is to sample weights $w_i$ according to a multinomial distribution and then sample the motion model of $x_i$ that was chosen. However, in the bootstrap filter the authors propagate the particles $\{(w_i,x^i_{k-1})\}$ one by one and I don't understand why it is equivalent to sampling from $\hat{p}(x_{k}|D_{k-1})$?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. Sample with replacement the $x_{k-1}^i$'s and apply the transition by $f_k$, then reweight by $p(y_k|x^i_k)$. Or do it all at once.

Comment: In the original paper, they propagate each particle $x^i_{k-1}$ through the transition function and then multiply by its weight, which is not same as sampling $x^i_{k-1}$ with replacement according to weights like you mentioned (in the first option each particle is propagated exactly ones and in the second option same particle can be propagated multiple times or not propagated at all) so I don't understand why it is equivalent. I am talking only about the prediction part, the update part is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original paper, I do not see the previous weights being propagated:

[image]

The authors thus assume (in the *Prediction* paragraph) the $x_{k-1}(i)$ are equally weighted, as being a sample from the distribution $p(x_{k-1}|D_{k-1})$. Once the propagation step is accomplished, they propose a resampling (or Bayesian bootstrap) using the observation densities $p(y_k|x^*_k(i))$ as weights.